# Mobius inversion for complex-valued functions

Tags: combinatorics

The wikipedia page on Mobius inversion formula mentions a generalization for complex valued functions F(x) and G(x), which is used in combinatorics.

[https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_inversion_formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula)

My question is how you prove that inversion formula is correct for complex values functions?

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity write, $f*μ = \sum_{d|n}f(n)μ(\frac{n}{d})$.

Let $U(n)=1$ for all n, we first show that $f*μ= I(n)$, which is 1 when n=1, and 0 otherwise.

When n=1, then $\sum_{d|1}U(n)μ(\frac{n}{d})=1$.

When n>1, write $n=p_1^{a_1}...p_r^{a_r}$, then

$\sum_{d|n}μ({d})=1+(μ(p_1)+...μ(p_r))+(μ(p_1p_2)+...+μ(p_{r-1}p_r))+μ(3-tuples)+...+μ(p_1...p_r) = 1 + {r\choose1} (-1) + {r\choose2}(-1)^2+ {r\choose3}(-1)^3+...+ {r\choose r}(-1)^r = (1-1)^r =0.$

It follows that $f=U*g \iff g=f*μ$

Comment: I see how that proves the general mobius inversion formula, but I dont see how it proves the case for complex valued functions.